# Can I power a Wemos D1 R2 via the VIN and GND pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, voltage

Can I power a Wemos D1 R2 via the VIN and GND pins?
If so, at what voltage?

Answer (score 2):

[Wemos D1 R2](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1:d1#features) has on-board regulator with input from power jack and Vin pin. The regulator is for 9 to 24 V.